# LocalStorage remove item from object using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, local-storage, javascript-objects

I would like to remove an item from localstorage object:

```
addToFavs: [{"fav-name":"fav-787336"},{"fav-name":"fav-255890"}]
```

I stored the information, then I checked if the item found, I should remove it:

```
/*** getID is the items clicked ***/

var retrievedData = localStorage.getItem("addToFavs");
    
    var parseData = jQuery.parseJSON(retrievedData);

    $.each(parseData, function(x,y){
        if(y['fav-name'] == getID){
            console.log(getID+' found on '+x);
            console.log(parseData[x]);
            localStorage.removeItem(parseData[x]);
            console.log(x+' removed');
        } else {
            console.log(getID+' NOT NOT found on '+x);
        }

}); // end $.each
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Use [`Array.prototype.filter()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter)

Comment: How can I implement it in my code? I tried so many ways but failed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot do this:

```
localStorage.removeItem(parseData[x]);
```

You need to either update the array you parsed, or create a new one, and then `stringify` it back to JSON, and `setItem` to update the value in localStorage. Because localStorage can only store Strings, not Arrays or Objects.

`filter` would be a nice way of doing it:

```
var jsonString = localStorage.getItem("addToFavs");
var arr = JSON.parse(jsonString);
// Filter to keep only those with a different ID than getID
arr = arr.filter(function(item) { return item['fav-name'] !== getID; });
// Store it back, stringified
localStorage.setItem("addToFavs", JSON.stringify(arr));
```

Answer (score 1):

1. The value in the local storage is a string
2. Read the local storage value by the key
3. Decode the string value
4. Apply the Array.prototype.filter function to filter the value out of the array
5. Encode the array value
6. Write it to local storage using the same key

Answer (score 0):

Not to freak you out or something

`addToFavs: [{"fav-name":"fav-787336"},{"fav-name":"fav-255890"}]`.  <---- in this line of code `addToFavs` is the item in local storage and not the object you stored.

and local storage only supports storage of type string:string as item:value, so

`localStorage.removeItem(parseData[x]);` <--- this line of code here is trying to look for an item, in your case

which is actually inside your stringified object that itself is value to `addToFavs` item,

hence you have to remove the item from the object and store the `addToFavs` again as illustrated below.

```js
var ls = window.localStorage;
ls.setItem('addToFavs', '[{"fav-name":"fav-787336"},{"fav-name":"fav-255890"}]');

var getId = 'fav-787336';

var item = JSON.parse(ls.getItem('addToFavs'));

var updatedItems = item.filter(val => (val['fav-name'] === getId));

console.log(updatedItems);

//update loacl storage again

ls.setItem('addToFavs', JSON.stringify(updatedItems))
```

the code won't run as localStorage access is not granted dues to security concerns feel free to run code in browser console.